# how can i prevent (winapi keyboard hook hooking keybd_event)?

Tags: c++

first, sorry my english!
hi guys, i want to make something
when i press the "x" then "ax"
this is code -----------------

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

HHOOK hKBHook;

UINT TimerId;
UINT TimerId1;

VOID CALLBACK DelayX(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
    keybd_event(65, 0, WM_KEYDOWN, 0);
    keybd_event(65, 0, WM_KEYUP, 0);
    keybd_event(88, 0, WM_KEYDOWN, 0);
    keybd_event(88, 0, WM_KEYUP, 0);
    KillTimer(NULL, TimerId);
}

VOID CALLBACK XSPlay(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
    PlaySound(TEXT("tocks.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
    KillTimer(NULL, TimerId1);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT pKey = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
        cout << pKey->vkCode << " ";
        switch (pKey->vkCode)
        {
            case 88:
            {
                PlaySound(TEXT("tocks.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
                KillTimer(NULL, TimerId1);
                TimerId1 = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 297, &XSPlay);
                TimerId = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 290, &DelayX);
        return 1;
            }
            case 19:
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKBHook);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    CallNextHookEx(hKBHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    HMODULE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    hKBHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, hInstance, NULL);
    MSG Msg;

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {DispatchMessage(&Msg);}

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKBHook);

    return 0;
}
```

the problem is
press x -> send ax -> hooked this x too -> send ax ---------- loop
and i'm really noob
maybe many another codes are need improvement.
give me your advise for learning C++ :)
thanks for reading!

Comment: Add `if ((pKey->flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) == 0)` so you ignore injected keys.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) You probably can use the extra info parameter to specify if this is your own simulation of X to prevent a loop

Comment: sorry but can you tell me more easier please? i saw that link but i couldn't know how to using dwExtraInfo